# Image content is changed after sending a mail using java spring

Tags: java, spring, email

I'm getting a weird error when sending email to multipeple.

This is simple html template mail

[image: mail template]

I declare 3 image tags to assign image content to the email

```java
InputStream inputStreamMN1 = CheckinApplication.class.getResourceAsStream("/image1.png");
InputStream inputStreamMN2 = CheckinApplication.class.getResourceAsStream("/image2.png");
DataSource fds1MN = new ByteArrayDataSource(inputStreamMN1.readAllBytes(), "image/png");
DataSource fds2MN = new ByteArrayDataSource(inputStreamMN2.readAllBytes(), "image/png");
```

The first and second images have fixed content, I took them from the resources folder. Then create 2 Datasource variables to save their content

The third image has the content of 1 qr code. I generate it automatically and then put the content into Datasource

```java
ImageIO.write(qrImage, "png", baos);
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
DataSource qrS = new ByteArrayDataSource(bytes, "image/png");
```

Finally, I assign 3 image variables to the email body and sent the email

```java
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
msg.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");
msg.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse(from, false));
msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(msg, true, "UTF-8");
helper.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from, mailName));
helper.setSentDate(new Date());
helper.setText(body, true);
helper.addTo(toLst);
helper.addInline("image1", fds1);
helper.addInline("image2", fds2);
helper.addInline("imageqr", qrS);
```

If correct, the recipient's email content will have 3 cid variables corresponding to the 3 values ​​I declared on the mail template.

[image: correct mail]

But with the error email, the cid content is changed and the image content on the email is also changed. The changed image content is not in my resources folder, nor is it in the recipient's computer

[image: error email]

I sent about 350 emails but only 1 email had this error

Hopefully someone here knows the reason and can explain it to me. Thank you

Comment: Happened to me once. The recipient used Outlook. I thought that was the reason for the error at first. But then it turned out that it was an antivirus software, or some firewall-like company thing in between, that checked and changed the byte contents of the pictures, as well as the internal `cid`s on the images. This was so long time ago that I can't remember details, but it's worth checking that possibility.

Comment: @JayC667 In my case, the recipient used Outlook too.

Comment: @JayC667 But if bytes contents of the pictures were change, why did it change to the cid of an existing image, not a random cid and cause the image display to fail?

Comment: There are/were hacks that can use JPEG decompression algorithms to execute malicious code. Probably the AV software re-codes the image files to make sure that not malicious code is transferred. Another reason might be down-sizing: In big companies, large image files often slowed down intranets. Whatever the reason, I do not know why someone would change the cid resource name, and not re-insert the new image under the old name. Too many problems that get created along the way. Maybe corpo rules... But if it changed the name to an invalid one, it would be unacceptably bad softaware, wouldn't it?

Comment: @JayC667 Thank for your comment. Maybe I need to talk with low-level system team. About error content image, I have a different opinion. I think I need to control the content I send to customers. If correct, it needs to be a valid and accurate photo. and if it's wrong, don't show it. It's possible that the image content in error is violent or sensitive content, then there could be a bigger problem. Anyway, thank you for your opinion